# Cannot read property 'functionName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on a react native project where I am trying to retrieve an array of json objects.  I am currently using the fetch function like so:

```
//*******************    require in root App.js  ***********

global.fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');


//*******************    API.js    *************************

import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

const api = {
 getData() {
  const url = 'http://.php?route=users';
  return fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());
 }
};

export { api };

//******************    dataRetrieval.js    ********************* 

//imports
import api.js form './filepath.js';

 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
   this.state = {
     email: '',
     password: '',
     error: '',
     loading: false,
     users: []
   };
 }

componentDidMount() {
  api.getData(this).then((res) => {
   this.setState({ users: res.getData });
  });
}
```

Project Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.2.0",
    "npm": "^6.4.1",
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.0",
    "react-native-fetch": "^2.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.12.1",
    "unfetch": "^3.1.1"
},
```

When I try and run the simulator I recieve an error saying that my `getData()` function is undefined and cannot be read.

Comment: Where are you importing / requiring `api` from `api.js`?

Comment: I have added import / require

Comment: is your import correct ?
import { api } from './api';

Comment: @DaltonPablo have you? Where?

Comment: @Phil above constructor

Answer (score 0):

You're incorrectly using export/import.

Either use `export default api` in your API.js file, or use `import { api } from './filepath.js'` in your dataRetrieval.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Then, Adding the upper answer, you should write the .catch.
it's not relevance your error, but have to get into the habit.

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

const api = {
getData() {
const url = 'http://.php?route=users';
 return fetch(url)
 .then((res) => res.json())
 .catch(err=> console.log(err)
 }
};
```

You can check for [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)